# Google Scripts Syntax

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, rhino

I am using Google Apps Scripts. I want to pass a 2D string array into a function as a web app, then access parts of the array within my function. What is the appropriate syntax for accessing things in Google Apps Scripts? Something like this?

```
function myFunction(stringArray){
    stringArray = stringArray || {('Name','testName'),('Topic','testTopic'),('Date','1/1/1')};

    //accessing stringArray
    var name = stringArray.Name;
    var topic = stringArray.Topic;
    var date = stringArray.Date;

    Logger.log(name+topic+date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dGQ4d7JF1U gives a good description.

```
var array = { name: 'AA', topic: 'BBB', date: 'CCCC'};
var name = array['name'];
var topic = array['topic'];
var date = array['date'];

Logger.log(name + topic + date);
```

This should output AABBBCCCC

Answer (score 1):

You are also able to access values using dot notation.

```
var obj = { "dogs": "woof" };

Logger.log(obj.dogs); // "woof"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
function myFunction({name, topic, date}){
    Logger.log(name+topic+date);
}
```